# Best way to define a class with private members that can be easily instantiated in a single line?

Tags: scala, groovy

Suppose I have the following scala classes  ( that needs to improve to address the concern
in this question and may not be valid scala classes):

```
@Entity
class Hotel extends Model {

    private var name: String = _;
    private var stars: Int = _;

    @Embedded
    private var address: Address = _;

    def someMethod() = {
     // do something

    }

  }

class Address {

    private var street: String = _;

    private var city: String = _;
    private var postCodet: String = _;

}
```

In groovy I can do this in single like:

```
def hotel = new Hotel(name: "some Hotel", stars: 5, address: new Address(street: "342 main", city: "edmond", postCode: "12345"))
```

Does Scala have something like that and how can I improve the class declarations shown above to improve the design. Note that I must have those annotations that comes from another Java library. Also once a class is instantiated or otherwise obtained from a database, I must be able to modify individual fields ( mutable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Address can be defined as:

```
class Address(var street:String, var city: String, var postCodet: String)
```

This assumes you want the variables to be modifiable later.

You can than create an Address with

```
new Address(street="street", city="city", postCodet="a1a1a1")
```

Hotel is a little more interesting because of the need for an annotation. I think this will do the trick for you:

```
class Hotel(var name:String, var stars:Int, @Embedded var address: Address) extends Model {
       def someMethod() = {...}
}
```

EDIT: Fixed @Embedded

If it doesn't, you may have to resort to something like:

```
class Hotel(var name:String, var stars:Int, address_in: Address) extends Model {
@Embedded
var address:Address = address_in

...
}
```

Note, if the variables on the object are not modifiable, you can use val rather than var on the class definition. This way, something like address.street will return the current value of street, but address.street = "new street address" will not compile.

Comment: Thanks thats very helpful. I will try that. Can you tell if I declare class like you mentioned are the variables considered private by default because I did not see private keyword? I don't even know if private ensures encapsulation in scala code (becaue we are still modifying fields directly) like clients can only access or modify variables through public getters and setters in Java class.

Comment: One thing about needing to change fields. If you don't _really_ need to change them, case classes and their `copy` method are great: `val newAddress = theAddress.copy(postcode="b2b2b2")`.

Comment: In Scala, the default access is public. If you wanted a field to be settable at construction, but not readable after that, you'd put class Address(private val street:String). If you haven't already, I'd seriously recommend acquiring Programming in Scala 2nd Edition (http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed)

Comment: @amc Nothing access fields directly in Scala. All access is made through getter and setter methods -- you just don't notice it because you never see the field itself.